Has anybody replaced a LM723 for a ua723 and experienced problems with drift and oscillations
Have replaced a LM723 DIL (obsolete)with a uA723 DIL in an exact same circuit board and the drift and oscillations are significantly worse. Tried multiple chips of different batches and the LM723 DIL is always better. Finally changed to a LM723  in a TO-100 package and performance is now on a par with the original LM723 DIL but far more expensive (not an issue as low production) The uA723 is not comparable as claimed. Has anyone else experienced this?

What manufacturers are involved here? Were the chips procured through reliable channels?The '723 is an ancient chip and has been copied/cloned by many companies including pre-1990 Eastern Europe and Taiwan.

The chips are from TI. Tested many from multiple reputable sources with same results

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looks like this is a known TI problem. They're basically shipping untested devices. Disappointing, but a bit surprising they admit it.

Due to the process technology when this device was released (1972)
some devices/lots exhibit signs of Zener Walkout which caused the
output voltage to change over time (it can possibly take minutes for
the output voltage to settle to it's final value). Zener Walkout
occurs due to trapped charges during the fab process and will cause a
Zener voltage to change and since a Zener is used to create the
voltage that the output voltage is referenced to you see a
corresponding change in the output voltage. The unfortunate part about
this is that it can take minutes for a device to settle while the
production tests that a device are significantly shorter so these
types of failures cannot be screened out. Since the number/amount of
trapped charge is variable due to normal process variations it may not
be seen on every lot which explains why your old unit’s/designs didn’t
exhibit the problem in the same circuit.
Knowing all of that but not knowing the scale of the number of devices
you’ll be producing I see three potential work arounds for you
Screen units by testing the output over time to see if they change, if
they don’t change then they are production worthy and use accordingly
(obviously this is only feasible for small scale) Burn in units at
high temp to move the trapped charges. This should yield a higher
percentage of usable parts.
Migrate the design to a new device.
If you provide us with the design specs for this power solution and we
may be able to find a newer device that is run on a much more modern
fab process or one that doesn’t use this topology of using a Zener to
create the reference voltage.


Looking at the TI UA723 product page there is no list of published errata. It's a pity that the known limitation of the device test procedure being unable to screen out the failure is "hidden" on a TI forum thread, rather than more visible on the product page.

As additional information to the answer found some more discussion of the problem on the TI forums:

UA723: "Drift is a one-time thing (“zener walkout”) that stabilizes after time", Output voltage is drifting during test.....!!!!! by Kyle Van Renterghem, Application Manager LDO Product Line, which:

Says the LM723H is an alternative. The product page says is currently an active produce. However, since the LM723H is a military grade part with a higher temperature range it is ~25 times more expensive than than the UA723.
Suggests a test fixture to be used:

I would recommend creating a test fixture which has many sockets that you can load many parts into and power them up at the same time.  The goal is to power up the devices while they are at high temperature for at least a few minutes to cause the trapped charge in the Zener to move, you can do that in  a couple different ways.

Put the board with the devices into an oven at 125C and power on the devices with minimal load

Positives: This makes it easier to find a usable input power supply since you don't have a lot of current being drawn from the power supply3
Negatives: Requires an oven, ovens can take a while to get to temp so the more units on the board the more efficient this approach will be.


Increase the power dissipation to self heat the silicon

Positives: Don't need an oven and the silicon will get to temp very quickly
Negatives: Less exact way of heating the die, you should going in and out of thermal shutdown (with the output turning on and off), and you need to make sure you have a supply or multiple supplies (with the board laid out for multiple supplies) that can handle the potentially large amount of current



Below is an example of a board that is made to go into an oven with ~80 units





UA723: Voltage drift information has an attached UA723 Vref drift over time (up to 24 hours) presentation with some data TI collected on the problem. Interestingly, the presentation which was attached by a TI employee is marked as TI Information – Selective Disclosure so it probably wasn't meant to be publicly available, but has now been on a TI webserver for the last 5 years.


As a simple work-around with minimum modification, you could add a precision voltage reference to replace the 723 - 7.15V internal Vref voltage, since Vref does not appear to be used internally, but only provides the reference for the voltage going to the Ninv input.
The Ref voltage at the Ninv input can be as low as 2V.
So, for example, you could use the common TL431 shunt reference, which has a 2.5V Ref voltage.
Of course the resistors at the 723 INV input would likely then need to be modified (to give 2.5V at the INV input) to get the same desired output voltage.
If that reference is not temperature stable enough for your requirements (which is comparable to the 723 data sheet Ref voltage spec), there are other, more stable references available.
Below is the LTspice sim of an example 723 circuit modified to use a TL431
2.5V reference, showing the output voltage for various settings of the U2 pot:


Looking at the datasheets for the TI versions of the µA723 and LM723 the LM version internal schematic is much more complicated. This may indicate that there are indeed differences besides packaging, or they've just dumbed the µA version schematic down a bit. That TI bothered to make both part numbers suggests that they are different devices that share a common functionality but aren't exact replacements for each other. If the µA723 is indeed a much simpler circuit that could account for the worse performance you are seeing.
Then of course you have to take into account other manufacturers having different implementations as well.

TI got the LM723 etc. when they acquired National Semiconductor. BTW, the internal schematic in my paper 1982 NS databook for the LM723 is identical to the uA723 schematic you linked. As of 1984 TI only made the uA723, so I would assume there are only the NS and the TI versions under the  present TI marque.
